# Why my Raspberry pi receive no packets using Ethernet?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ethernet, interface, packet

I use a Raspberry pi 3b. The OS is Raspbian jessie.

I don't understand why I can't connect with any RJ45 cable, and only wireless connection works. The cable rj45 is straight.

The step I did to resolve my problem :

1. Remove wireless connection in case there is a conflict when
   configuring the interfaces. Now there isn't anymore the wlan0
   interface.
2. Disable firewall.
3. Configure manually the eth0 interface in the etc/network/interfaces
   to make the configuration automatically when booting the system. The
   result of ifconfig is that I have a lot of packets Transmited by
   eth0, but no packets received, but IP address is correct.

`root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ifconfig`:

```
eth0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:fa:42:e6  
  inet addr:(masked but correct IP)  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
  inet6 addr: (masked but correct) Scope:Link
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:4384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:706089 (689.5 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:4719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:4719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
  RX bytes:373537 (364.7 KiB)  TX bytes:373537 (364.7 KiB)
```

I've tried using three different cables, but none worked.

EDIT: Informations about `ethtool eth0` command
[image: Eththool result]

EDIT 2 : dmesg output
[image]

Comment: `apt-get install ethtool` with the wireless interface, then edit the question, and add the output of `ethtool eth0` please. Looking at the `dmesg` output *might* help.

Comment: Hello, I edited my message, but for the dmesg output is it correct that I have to execute : dmesg | ethtool eth0 ?  I've never used it yet.

Comment: Just run `dmesg | less`

Comment: I would advise doing ssh to your raspberry and pasting the output of ethtool as text is it not complete. However from what is there it seems ok; where are you connecting it?

Comment: I'm connecting it to a router. I will edit with the dmseg output. Thanks.

Comment: What is the router brand and model?

Comment: It's the Swisscom's internet-box plus. You can find more info on this box on this site:  https://www.swisscom.ch/fr/clients-prives/aide/peripheriques/internet-router/internetbox.html

Comment: My first be was a different VLAN, however that would not leave 0 bytes in RX but residual traffic -or maybe, if it is entirely isolated; maybe an very strange administratively disabled port, or you are using a port destined for voIP/video? I would go to the admin web interface of that router, and check the config of that port. Or ask for the ISP support. I bet it is not a Linux problem: btw, you should use the yellow ports.